# Comparison for 75 tables in two different SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do a column by column, row by row comparison for 75 tables in two different databases. The tables contain up to 165 million records.

I need to determine if there are any missing records, and we need to identify any columns that contain different values. Potential problems include decimal errors.

Comment: [tablediff Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/tablediff-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this:

- You can create linked server to another server and do comparison using EXCEPT , LEFT OUTER JOIN etc. Refer to [Sql comparison with two tables](https://www.sqlshack.com/compare-tables-sql-server/)
- You can use tablediff.exe utility to do comparison between tables. Refer to [Tablediff.exe](http://sqlsuperfast.com/page/TableDiffexe-SQL-Server-Comparision-Utility.aspx)
- You can use third party tools like Redgate Data Compare. Refer to [Sql data compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)